# facing issues while running chaincode locally using docker

Tags: go, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger

i m getting below error while running learn-chaincode example on my local system please provide me the suitable solution for the mentioned error

```
$ go build
# github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the Fabric team introduced "nopkcs11" tag to bypass the problem - https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2854

I used the following command to build my chain code:

```
go build -tags nopkcs11
```

Comment: It was mentioned here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#building-chaincode

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! If you use Visual Studio Code as windows editor you can add this to your settings with the following setting: "go.buildTags": "nopkcs11"

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the Learn Chaincode example from https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode was being followed.  Note that this example is for use with Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.

The message is related to a PKCS11 package that is referenced by the example.  This PKCS package requires a gcc compiler in order to build.  I would suggest obtaining a gcc compiler and then trying to build the example again.

Comment: thanks for giving the information but would you suggests me how to get a gcc compiler